# UILabel don't adjust in height to fit the text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, font-size

I know there is a lot of post about `UILabel` and it's size but i was unable to find a answer for my problem.

I have some `UILabels` with a text on 1 line, no more and don't want more lines, and the text is set to a minimum font scale to adjust. In portrait mode, the screen has enough space in heightand don't scale my UILabel in height to a critical point.

In landscape mode, i'm short in height and the `UILabel` is very small in height and the text is cut on the top and bottom.

I have tested everyting i have read like:

- set line breaks to clip mode
- use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;`

In every case, the text fit only in width but don't care about height.

Should i use some ugly hack to calcul the font size depending on the label height myself or have i miss something ?

Comment: post your code, to see if you missed smth

Comment: Everything is in interface builder except if i try to add the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth line by code. I can't show you any code. If you want to reproduce it, create a new project, put a uilabel into it with a big font size with minimum scale of 0.1 and make the height apect ration something like 5 or 10% of the screen height. After this, play a bit with screen rotation and you will have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(22, 50, 280, 150);
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[myLabel setText:finalRecipe];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

CGFloat fontSize = 0.0f;
labelFrame.size = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font
                            minFontSize:myLabel.minimumFontSize
                         actualFontSize:&fontSize
                               forWidth:labelFrame.width
                        lineBreakMode:myLabel.lineBreakMode];

myLabel.frame = labelFrame;
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```